# How to enable disable fields using Java Script in Webform

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created a web page "Default.aspx" in which I have taken fields: 
First Name, Last Name, Account Titling, Titling(radio button list), AccountNumber and AccountFormat
under the "Default.aspx" page, I have used a radio button list also, whose values are Yes and No. If I choose Yes, then the following fields visibility should set to false:

First Name, Last Name

If I choose "NO", then the following fields visibility should set to true:

Account Titling, Account number

For this, I have written the below Java Script code in "Default.aspx"

```
function EnableDisableTaxID() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=rdOpeningSubAccount.ClientID %>") != null) {

            var openSubAccountList = document.getElementById('<%= rdOpeningSubAccount.ClientID  %>');
            var fbo1RadioList = document.getElementById('<%=fbo1RadioButtonList.ClientID %>').value;
            var isOpenSubAccount;

            if (openSubAccountList != null) {

                var openSubAccount = openSubAccountList.getElementsByTagName("input");

                for (var i = 0; i < openSubAccount.length; i++) {

                    if (openSubAccount[i].checked) {

                        isOpenSubAccount = openSubAccount[i].value;
                        alert("Print" + isOpenSubAccount);
                    }
                }
            }
            alert(typeof(isOpenSubAccount));
            if (isOpenSubAccount == 'true') {
                FirstName.visible = true;
                LastName.visible = false;
                AccountTitling.visible = true;
                lblFirstName.visible=false;
                lblLastName.visible=false;

            }
            else if (isOpenSubAccount == 'false') {
                AccountTitling.visible = true;
                AccountNumber.visible = false;
                lblAccountTitling.visible = true;
                lblAccountNumber.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting the required value from the Radio button list, however, when I go to check if the selected value of the radiobuttonlist is true, then the code above does not work. I dont know what am I missing. I know that directly using the below code will not work:

```
if (isOpenSubAccount == 'true') {
                FirstName.visible = true;
                LastName.visible = false;
                AccountTitling.visible = true;
                lblFirstName.visible=false;
                lblLastName.visible=false;

            }
```

Please help as I m stuck here...

Comment: Do you use `Visible` property to hide server controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visible = false;

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').style.visibility="hidden";
```

For Visible = true;

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').style.visibility="visible";
```

To Enable:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').disabled = false;
```

To Disable:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

No; document.getElementById will only get the element with the ID you specify (the HTML spec is quite clear that only one element on a page can have a specific ID).

Each radio button has a different ID attribute, but if you look at the HTML source of a page, you will see that all radio buttons in the list have the same NAME attribute.  This is what you should use "the name of the radio button".

onclick="GetRadioButtonValue('<%= radiobuttonlist1.ClientID %>')"

```
function GetRadioButtonValue(id)

        {

            var radio = document.getElementsByName(id);

            for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++)

            {

                if (radio[j].checked)

                    alert(radio[j].value);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be done for

**Non Visible**

```
document.getElementById('id-name').style.display='none';
```

**Visible**

```
document.getElementById('id-name').style.display='block';
```

**Disable**

```
document.getElementById('id-name').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

**Enable**

```
document.getElementById('id-name').removeAttribute('disabled');
```